# Efficiently piping many generators without recursion errors

Tags: python, pipe, generator

Suppose I have a Python method that chains together a large number of generators. Here, chaining does *not* refer to returning the results of all iterators one after the other but to using the output of one iterator as input for the other generator.

How could I formulate the method so that it (1) is not prone to stack overflows and (2) remains efficient, i.e. does not require the evaluation of the complete generator when just one value is requested.

An example with 3 different implementations of chaining the `chain` generator `n` times:

```
from itertools import chain
from functools import reduce

mygenerator = chain

def f1(n):
    result = []
    for i in range(n):
        result = mygenerator(result, [1])
    return result

def f2(n):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: mygenerator(x, [1]), chain([[1]], range(n-1)))

def f3(n):
    result = []
    for i in range(n):
        result = list(mygenerator(result, [1]))
    return result
```

Running `f1` or `f2` with a large argument (say 100000) leads to an error. Running `f3`, instead, is inefficient.

I know that it is possible to reformulate each recursion as a for loop. How do I do this here in a pythonic way?

Comment: Rewriting the recursion as a `for` loop means *not* nesting a bazillion generators - you'll have to rewrite your generator to not delegate to another generator.

Comment: Nesting a bazillion generators would be slow even if it didn't overflow the stack, because you'd have to suspend and resume a bazillion generators each time you want an element.

Comment: (Also `itertools.chain` isn't a generator. Generators are a specific type of iterator, created by `yield` or genexps.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That makes sense. Is there a design pattern that helps me to avoid this issue? Thanks for the comment regarding `itertools.chain`. I seek to apply the answer to the question to *real* generators. `chain` is just used for the example. I believe it behaves like a generator here.